# Swap not mounting on a fresh installation

Tags: mount, fstab, swap

```
~$ blkid
/dev/sda5: UUID="2a5b14e5-ac61-42c5-8240-c8aa144b07b3" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda6: UUID="685a9f14-4680-4620-a498-126f1113a471" TYPE="swap"

~$ sudoedit /etc/fstab
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=2a5b14e5-ac61-42c5-8240-c8aa144b07b3 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=685a9f14-4680-4620-a498-126f1113a471 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

As far as I can see, everything is perfect. But it does not mount on boot. I can do `umount -a` after booting, and that works. Live sessions also mount the partition automagically. Help?

I have already seen and read the answers to [System not mounting swap partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38533/system-not-mounting-swap-partition) question. It does not apply in my case as the swap entry in `fstab` is already at the end. Something else is cause the issue here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't worry!

1. Format `/dev/sda6` to be a valid swap `mkswap /dev/sda6`
2. Activate the swap by `swapon /dev/sda6`
3. Additionally modify `/etc/fstab` to **make swap start after every boot**. The swap line will probably be already there. You will just need to update `UUID` received as output of step 1.

Comment: I'll try this, but why won't the existing swap mount on boot?

Comment: @Oxwivi I don't know BUT I think it's a bug since I also face this problem if I create a swap partition during installation, Ubuntu not detect that partition on boot. Then you need to recreate the swap area and active and add new UUID in fstab file. I also deleted duplicate flag, sry. cool! :)

Comment: That worked. Though I would've liked to figure out the reason why to avoid recreating swap after every installation, but oh well.