# Lost Swap Partition

Tags: partitioning, fstab, swap, 14.10

I set up a new Ubuntu Partition a few days ago. Yesterday I installed the Kubuntu-Desktop to replace the Unity thing.

Since I installed the new desktop the Linux-Swap partition won't work anymore and not even recognized as Swap. I don't know how that could happen.

Does anybody of you knows how to fix a problem like that? I understand it has something to do with `/etc/fstab`, but don't really know what to do with it.

The Swap Partition is 4GB and was set up during installation of Ubuntu.

If it helps, here is the result of: `cat /etc/fstab`

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=345e5bbd-d951-4376-8f4b-724be9d0417b /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=9669db10-3a55-47cd-8c49-e8e4520ca2d3 /boot           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /home was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=38b3f3ac-c96b-4f01-8fcf-eac44c6ed28f /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
#UUID=6ea517a3-a80a-4acb-bea9-4efea2a71acf none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

Edit: Since there was a Question regarding: `cat /etc/crypttab`

```
cryptswap1 UUID=6ea517a3-a80a-4acb-bea9-4efea2a71acf /dev/urandom swap,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256
```

Comment: It seems you're using an encrypted swap partition. Can you provide the content of `/etc/crypttab` please? You can [edit] your question to improve it with additional info.

Comment: I edited the question with /etc/crypttab. Hope it helps. I only clicked by installation to encrypt the Home Folder.

Comment: Thanks. Have an upvote for a good question with all the necessary info. Do you want your swap partition to be encrypted in the future too or does an unencrypted one suffice?

Comment: I don't need an encrypted swap partition. I just want an working one. If I would have known in the Beginning that an encrypted Homefolder messes with everything, I would not have done that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to recreate your swap partition as following steps:

**Step 1.** Format `/dev/sda6` to be a valid swap `mkswap /dev/sda6`

**Step 2.** Activate the swap by `swapon /dev/sda6`

**Step 3.** Additionally modify `/etc/fstab` to **make swap start after every boot**. The swap line will probably be already there. You will just need to update `UUID` received as output of step 1.

For example in your case REMOVE these lines (**IF you don't want Encrypted swap partition**):

```
#UUID=6ea517a3-a80a-4acb-bea9-4efea2a71acf none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

And add this line instead at the end with NEW UUID that you get in step 1:

```
UUID=0c9f1cb4-a539-4ca4-8eb2-712d0efc3d10 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

[see here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/524274/swap-not-mounting-on-a-fresh-installation) and my answer there

> **IF you want to keep your Encrypted swap partition do the following
>   steps:**
>
> First things first, we need to know where your swap file is located on
>   your hard drive. `dmesg` can help here (or you could also check
>   `/etc/fstab`)
>
> So in your case you can see the swap is on `/dev/sda6`. Next thing to
>   do is ensure the system is fully up to date, turn swap off so we can
>   work with the partition and install the necessary files. Ensure to
>   replace `/dev/sda6` with the partition you got from `dmesg` (or
>   `/etc/fstab`) in the step above:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get upgrade
> sudo swapoff /dev/sda6
> sudo apt-get install lvm2 cryptsetup
> ```
>
> Next up, load the module and verify its running.
>
> ```
> $ sudo modprobe dm-crypt
> ```
>
> You should see something like below
>
> ```
> $ sudo lsmod | egrep 'aes|dm_crypt'
> dm_crypt               12928  0 
> aes_i586                8124  1 
> aes_generic            27484  1 aes_i586
> ```
>
> Now we clear the partition of existing data by filling it with random
>   data. This has two purposes, first so that any old unencrypted data is
>   overwritten and second so that your encrypted data does not stand out
>   if your drive is analysed. What I mean by this is, if you have 750 meg
>   of unused swap and only 250 meg used, then 3/4 of your drive will
>   contain no data at all, just zeros. This makes the encrypted data
>   stick out like a sore thumb. If you fill the drive with random data,
>   the encrypted data just ‘blends in’
>
> ```
> $ sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sda6 bs=1M
> ```
>
> Again, replace `/dev/sda6` with the partition you got from `dmesg` or
>   `fstab`. This command will take a while (about 10 mins or so) and
>   should produce output similar to this:
>
> ```
> dd: writing `/dev/sda6': Input/output error
> 1028+0 records in
> 1027+0 records out
> 1077510144 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 642.306 s, 1.7 MB/s
> ```
>
> Then you need to tell `crypttab` to set up the partition as encrypted
>   swap, again ensure to change `/dev/sda6` to your partition:
>
> ```
> sudo echo cryptoswap /dev/sda6 /dev/urandom cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256,size=256,hash=sha256,swap >> /etc/crypttab
> ```
>
> Next, edit the `/etc/fstab` file and search for the line with ‘swap’
>   in it. Comment that line out by inserting a `#` character at the
>   beginning of the line, then insert the following line and save the
>   file:
>
> ```
> /dev/mapper/cryptoswap none swap sw 0 0
> ```
>
> That is now your system set up with encrypted swap. Reboot your system
>   for the changes to be picked up and the encrypted swap to be started.
>   To ensure that the swap partition is encrypted after you boot you can
>   check `dmesg` again, it should specifically mention cryptoswap:
>
> ```
> dmesg | grep swap
>  [   73.063397] Adding 979924k swap on /dev/mapper/cryptoswap.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:979924k
> ```
>
> If you notice a delay during boot time, or see a message such as
>   ‘waiting for swap’ then move the mouse around a bit. It means the
>   system is low on entropy to generate random data for initialization of
>   the encryption. It should only take a second or two.
>
> <sub>[source](http://iwtf.net/2010/01/05/encrypting-your-ubuntu-swap-partition/)</sub>

Comment: Could you please provide more information to step 3? I changed the UUID in the fstab with the Line I received in first step, but it still won't be recognised after reboot. But it will be recognised after swapon.

Comment: Could you please post the output of step1?

Comment: This won't work with the entry in `crypttab`, because it'll reformat `6ea517a3-a80a-4acb-bea9-4efea2a71acf` (sda6) with an encrypted swap partition on every boot.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Then it also needs to update the UUID from step1 in `crypttab` file and it will work after updating `fstab` file by `mount -a`.

Comment: The output of step 1 is: UUID:0c9f1cb4-a539-4ca4-8eb2-712d0efc3d10

Comment: @KasiyA: Not entirely, but a good explanation would exceed the scale of a comment. If Severus15 divulged, if they'd like their swap partition encrypted or not ([as I have asked them before](https://askubuntu.com/questions/540162/ubuntu-14-10-lost-swap-partition/540167?noredirect=1#comment739258_540162)), I'll write up an answer of my own.

Comment: @Severus15 Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

[αғsнιη's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/540167/175814) is on the right track but forgets to get rid of the `crypttab` entry and fails to explain in detail how to change `fstab`:

> Try to recreate your swap partition as following steps:
>
> 1. Format `/dev/sda6` to be a valid swap `mkswap /dev/sda6`
> 2. Activate the swap by `swapon /dev/sda6`

And then:

3. Remove the last line of `fstab` (`/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0`), uncomment the previous line and replace the UUID with that of the newly formatted swap device, e. g.:

   ```
   UUID=0c9f1cb4-a539-4ca4-8eb2-712d0efc3d10 none  swap  sw  0 0
   ```
4. Remove or comment the line in `/etc/crypttab` or remove or rename that file altogether.

You can also reuse the old swap partition UUID, if in step 1 you do:

```
mkswap --uuid 6ea517a3-a80a-4acb-bea9-4efea2a71acf /dev/sda6
```

Comment: I have also mentioned all the steps but NOT step 4 AND Uh yes I forget uncomment that line:)

Comment: Yes, but your step 3 was hardly understandable even for somebody who knew what you meant (= me) – especially with the two different cases (encrypted vs. unencrypted).

Comment: Now I think it's understandable :? if not feel free to edit. Thank you