# Long boot time, upower.service

Tags: boot

Recently I noticed my boot time got significantly longer. I forgot what I did but I manage to find what was taking so long.

> upower.service +55.027s
>
> May 26 02:35:01 pc-desktop systemd[1]: Starting Daemon for power management...
>
> May 26 02:35:56 pc-desktop systemd[1]: Started Daemon for power management.

So that takes 55 seconds to start. Anyone know why and how to make it faster again?

Comment: Me too. I just upgraded from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04.3. I found all sorts of things, like https://askubuntu.com/questions/760694/really-slow-boot-on-16-04#764012 and https://askubuntu.com/questions/939577/16-04-suffering-slow-boot-times-on-crucial-mx300-ssd-systemd-analyze-blame-show#939700. I have not solved it.