# Ubuntu 17.04 takes about three and half hours to boot

Tags: boot, 17.04, systemd, plymouth, apparmor

I recently installed Ubuntu 17.04 on my laptop that has 4 GB RAM, 1 TB Disk space, and 64 bit processor. To my horror, it takes about three and half hours to boot-up. I ran the following commands with their corresponding outputs below.

```
Output of systemd-blame
```

> Startup finished in 8.860s (firmware) + 4.572s (loader) + 5.593s
>   (kernel) + 3h 34min 27.734s (userspace) = 3h 34min 46.761s

```
Output of systemd-blame analyze
```

> [Snapshot of the output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hkhsn.png)

So, the two processes that are causing this traumatizing slow boot-up times are

- apparmor.service, and
- plymouth-read-write.service

I couldn't find anything comprehensible about these two processes to indicate their importance during start-up. Can anyone provide some insights and help me speed up the bootup time through either disabling them or suggesting a way around?

Comment: That is one amazing boot time.

Comment: Something seems misconfigured. Check your logs for errors and see https://askubuntu.com/questions/760694/really-slow-boot-on-16-04 . Check your swap partition and make the edits in /etc/systemd/system.conf . Does a live flash drive take this long ?

Comment: No @bodhi.zazen, a flash drive doesn't take this long. Let me check swap and other partitions.

Comment: What about booting an old kernel ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen,
1) The UUIDs obtained from sudo blkid & /etc/fstab matched exactly. However, there was no entry for 'swap' in the output from former and was 
` /swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0`
in latter.
Could this be the problem?

2) I uncommented
_DefaultTimeoutStartSec=90s_, 
_DefaultTimeoutStopSec=90s_, 
_DefaultRestartSec=100ms_ in _/etc/systemd/system.conf_ . I want to get a clearance from you, before I restart my computer to check if it works.

3) I will try booting an old kernel after I test the effect of point 2.

Comment: 100 ms is probably too short. I would stay with the 90 s default.