# Xubuntu takes long time to boot

Tags: boot, xubuntu

I have dual booted my desktop. It has Windows 8.1 and Xubuntu 16.04.3 LTS.
When I select Xubuntu from GRUB menu, it takes to long to boot into Xubuntu. The screen stays like this for a long time.

[image: Xubuntu boot screen]

On presssing <kbd>Escape</kbd> from the keyboard, I observe a blank black screen.

After some time, Xubuntu finally boots up.

I have tried using Boot-Repair and also followed [Really slow boot on 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/760694/701605) but nothing helped.

Boot summary is available here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/26034596/

Output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain`:

```
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 41.822s
└─multi-user.target @1min 41.822s
  └─ntp.service @1min 41.780s +41ms
    └─network-online.target @1min 41.778s
      └─NetworkManager-wait-online.service @1min 34.529s +7.248s
        └─NetworkManager.service @1min 32.030s +2.444s
          └─dbus.service @1min 31.962s
            └─basic.target @1min 31.960s
              └─sockets.target @1min 31.960s
                └─snapd.socket @1min 31.936s +23ms
                  └─sysinit.target @1min 31.936s
                    └─apparmor.service @15.229s +941ms
                      └─local-fs.target @15.227s
                        └─run-user-1000-gvfs.mount @1min 58.217s
                          └─run-user-1000.mount @1min 57.032s
                            └─local-fs-pre.target @15.225s
                              └─systemd-remount-fs.service @15.161s +63ms
                                └─system.slice @1.714s
                                  └─-.slice @1.627s
```

Comment: Please show the result of: `systemd-analyze critical-chain`

Comment: when you boot. highlight ubuntu and press "e" to edit. change "quiet splash" to "nosplash" then pres F10 to boot. I suspect that it is waiting for a drive to mount

Comment: @WillemK where should i post output of the command. Should I answer my question or make an edit?

Comment: You can see the result [here]
(https://pastebin.com/ex0C5pf5)

Comment: I support Ravery's suspicion that some drive cannot be mounted. Now please show us the results of: `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid`  and `cat /etc/fstab`.

Comment: @ravery your answer helped, wekll I would like to know what it did, and whether i need to do it every time?

Comment: What Ravery's suggestion does is now showing messages generated during the boot process. Is does not repair anything, the boot time is probably still the same.

Comment: @ravery: I actually did not look further than the `run-user-1000.mount @1min 57.032s`.  That made me think a partition fails to mount; I think the swap. Hence my comment to show uuid's and fstab.

Comment: @WillemK -- I agree,  there is a huge jump there.

Comment: ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 24 20:53 18D2-255E -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 24 20:53 829E56D89E56C477 -> ../../sda3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 24 20:53 93424c02-5dc5-4aab-af3b-1acb471eca47 -> ../../sda6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 24 20:53 A2605BD8605BB1B1 -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 24 20:53 ef66677d-b68d-44bd-88bd-6b32f30eb1cb -> ../../sda7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Nov 24 20:53 F062D01F62CFE884 -> ../../sda2

Comment: @WillemK My swap partion was not mounting automatically on startup. So i fixed that following steps from [SwapFaq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq)
I think that solved the problem.

Comment: SwapFaq is of course a good source from a educational perspective. For me/us it is nice to know what steps exactly did you take?  I mean, it would have sufficed to follow my Answer. You conclude saying `I think that solved my problem.` So be sure your swap is mounted, issue `lsblk` and you should see a line with [SWAP] in it, If present, you're ok.

Comment: @WillemK 
"[SWAP]" is present when I run "lsblk".
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Boot summary:
Your sda7 (swap) has : `UUID:ef66677d-b68d-44bd-88bd-6b32f30eb1cb`.
Your `/etc/fstab` has: `UUID=b66d26d9-8ef1-4192-ac02-02ac6c52b4f9`.
You need to change /etc/fstab to use the first UUID.

Comment: This has drastically reduced boot time.
but now I don't see that Xubuntu logo and that loading symbol, just a blank screen for about 10 seconds and then it jumps to login screen.
Well this works for me, but I would prefer that Xubuntu image instead of blank screen.

Comment: Look at the answer given previously by Ravery about "nosplash". Alter that to "quiet splash". That Xubuntu image is the 'splash' screen.

Comment: I checked for that and it was back to  'quiet splash'. Is that usual.
i think there is an option to edit that through GRUB configuration file.

Comment: I found this under
$gksu gedit /etc/default/grub 
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""